# Problems to include QT Liraries

Tags: c++, include, qt5, libraries

I'm currently learning Qt and I'm having some problems to include libraries to my visual studio project. I have installed the Qt5 libraries with vcpkg and used the command vcpkg integrate install correctly.

In my project I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "hello";

}
```

Very simple. besides that I have the following configuration in vcpkg properties

[Properties vcpkg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP2xq.png)

And i`m having the following two errors:

Cannot open source file "QApplication"
Cannot open include file qt5/QtWidgets/QApplication: no such file or directory

How can I include the librarie?

Comment: AFAIK there's no "QtApplication" header. Do you perhaps mean "QApplication" or "QCoreApplication"? I think you just mistyped the header/type name.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mistyped. I mean "QApplication"

Comment: Unsure what that vcpkg installs but feels your VS does know nothing about Qt. Might be you need to open Extensions > Manage Extensions > Online, in your VS, search for "Qt Visual Studio Tools" ... and then install those. And then perhaps using those tools you can create (or import) Qt-using projects edible for that IDE.